# Simple Plist. No output. What gives?

Tags: plist, launchd

I'm trying find exactly what's wrong with a larger job that I'm trying to schedule with launchd for the first time.  So I made the simplest python file I could think of, `print 'running test'`, titled it `com.schedulertest.plist` and then made a plist file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.schedulertest.py.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>arch</string>
        <string>-i386</string>
        <string>/usr/bin/python2.7</string>
        <string>/Users/user/Documents/Python_Alerts_Project/schedulertest.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then I saved it in `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/` and ran:

```
launchctl load com.schedulertest.plist
```

I should be getting the print output from my py script every 60 seconds, right?  I don't see anything though -- is there an obvious fault in my script or process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was not a big deal, but it might help others to share the solution.  I had simply forgotten, as we will when moving around several virtualenvs, which python I was in.  If you're having trouble and your `.plist` and script seem well-formed, it won't hurt to run `which python` etc, and check the result against the path you're listing in your program arguments.

Answer (score 0):

#### Troubleshooting

- To debug `.plist`, you can check the log for any error, e.g.

  ```
  tail -f /var/log/system.log
  ```

  To specify custom log, use:

  ```
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/myjob.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/myjob.log</string>
  ```
- To find the latest exit status of the job, run:

  ```
  launchctl list com.schedulertest.plist
  ```
- To make sure the syntax is correct, use `plutil` command.

See: [Debugging `launchd` Jobs section of Creating Launch Daemons and Agents page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).